# ProgressDialog keep loading till all the three Tab in Tabview Load the Content on individual Tab Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-progressbar

I have set `Tabview` in my `Activity`.When Login is successfull I am going to `ActivityTwo` where I am calling the `TabView` Fragment.Each `Fragment` loads data from Api and set it in `ReyclerView`.In each Fragment I am showing `ProgressDialog`  before Api call and dismiss it after data loads.But the problem is when TabView Fragment is replaced Api call of all the 3 Tabs take place and eventhough  the Data on First Tab is loaded progress dialog keeps loading and manually I need to dismiss it by touching screen ?
This is code for  First Tab data call

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.current_status, container, false);
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------        
    pullRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.pullRefresh);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    context = recyclerView.getContext();
    controller = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(context, R.anim.layout_fall_down);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setTitle("Fetching Records");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
          getData();
    progressDialog.show();


    return v;
}
```

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

put this on your **LAST** `onResponse` if the data has successfully loads.

```
if(progressDialog.isShowing()){
progressDialog.dismiss
}
```

**BONUS TIP**

always add  `progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);` and `progressDialog.setCancelable(false);`

this disable the touch on outside when `progressDialog` is loading o prevent UI interruption